# How to implement emotion detection with tensorflow lite?

Tags: mobile, tensorflow-lite

I want to implement mood detection with Tensorflow but I don't have clear understaning how to start .
Can I find  already existed model trained for emotion detection ?

Answer (score 0):

[Tensorflow for poets](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/#0) is a good introduction to using tensorflow lite. You can start with that and then look into "What's next" section for further reading.